# How to use passin with OpenSSL on Windows?

Tags: openssl

I am attempting to use open ssl to extract a .pem private key from a .pfx file which uses a passhrase.

When I do this:

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -passin pass:foobar -out key.pem
```

It then prompts me for the password (STDIN). However as you can see above I am trying to supply the password myself via `-passin pass:foobar`

Where am I going wrong?

P.S If I enter the password when prompted it works. But I want to avoid the prompt and to supply the password.

My openssl version is

```
OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018
```

Answer (score 3):

After further experimenting I have found that using both passin and passout args seems to fix this issue. However that seems wrong to me?

i.e this works:

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -passout pass:foo -passin pass:foo -nocerts -out key.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

Some openssl parameters are picky about their order on the command line. Try:

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe pkcs12 -passin pass:foobar -in cert.pfx -out key.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -passout pass:foo -passin pass:Initfoo -nocerts -out key-encrypted.key`
```

It's right. Because you must set password to the private key.
If you want to fully exclude password.
You must use additional command `openssl rsa -in key-encrypted.key -out key-decrypted.key -passin pass:foo`
And also check the key-encrypted.key & decrypted.key

[Good explanation but on Russian](https://blog.bissquit.com/unix/zametki-konvertiruem-pfx-v-key-i-crt/)